# how to use the toggleClass fuction in mutiple places?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

i dont know how to make the whole text show when the down arrow is clicked. here's what i tried,it works for only one text box, but when i make 2 or more of them, it doesnt work?

THE ONE THAT WORKS

```css
body{
    background-color: dimgray;
}
.box{
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 0.1px solid #dadada;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.box-content{
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.box-expand{
    height: auto !important;    
}
    
.box-opt{
    float: right;
}
.box-opt a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: #646464;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e74aa8f5bb.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" id="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content" id="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    <script>
        $("#box-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".box-content").toggleClass("box-expand");
        });
    </script>
```

it works for only one text box, but when i make 2 or more of them, it doesnt work?

THE ONE DOESNT ORK

```css
body{
    background-color: dimgray;
}
.box{
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 0.1px solid #dadada;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box-content{
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.box-expand{
    height: auto !important;    
}
    
.box-opt{
    float: right;
}
.box-opt a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: #646464;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e74aa8f5bb.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" id="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content" id="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    <script>
        $("#box-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".box-content").toggleClass("box-expand");
        });
    </script>
    
</div><div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" id="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content" id="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    <script>
        $("#box-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".box-content").toggleClass("box-expand");
        });
    </script>
    
</div><div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" id="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content" id="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    <script>
        $("#box-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".box-content").toggleClass("box-expand");
        });
    </script>
    
</div><div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" id="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content" id="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    <script>
        $("#box-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".box-content").toggleClass("box-expand");
        });
    </script>
    
</div>
```

Comment: ID should be unique. You should not use `box-toggle` multiple times in the DOM. And you will also need a specific selector instead of `.box-content` to toggle class, so that each toggle place would be independent.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID -- they are meant to be specific to one element. That being said I would change box-toggle to a class rather than ID and also remove id="box-content" on your boxes. You also don't need to place the script after every single box -- just once will do:

```
$('.box-toggle').click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 
$(this).parents('.box').find('.box-content').toggleClass('box-expand');
});
```

That way you are targeting only the box you are clicking within.

```css
body{
    background-color: dimgray;
}
.box{
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 0.1px solid #dadada;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box-content{
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.box-expand{
    height: auto !important;    
}
    
.box-opt{
    float: right;
}
.box-opt a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: #646464;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e74aa8f5bb.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" class="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    
</div><div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" class="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    
</div><div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" class="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    
</div><div class="box">
   
   <div class="box-opt">
        <a href="#" class="box-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
    </div>
    
    <p class="box-content">this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 this is an awsome comment bout this post this is an awsome comment bout this posttis is 7 </p>         
                    
    <script>
        $('.box-toggle').click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 
$(this).parent().parent().find('.box-content').toggleClass('box-expand');
});
    </script>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the first issue i spot here is you are using the same ID on multiple elements. Thats why the last down arrow is the only one that seems to work.

Reason being - it is the last element that matches the ID you are looking for in your HTML.
You could use the classes instead and attach a jQuery each loop to apply the click listener to each of the elements

Try this:

```
// Iterate over each '.box' class found
// Inside the Each function we can add parameters that help
// us identify the elements we are dealing with

jQuery('.box').each(function(i,e)) 
{
    // Make '.box' into a jQuery object that we can use
    t = jQuery(e);

    // Look for the toggle inside current box
    currentToggle = t.find('.box-opt > a');

    // Find box content to add class to
    textContainer = t.find('.box-content');

    // Apply the click listener to **EACH** element
    currentToggle.on('click',function(e){

         // Stop the browser from adding a '#' to the url and causing the
         // window to jump up
         e.preventDefault();
         textContainer.toggleClass('box-expand');
    });
}
```

That should get you the result you're looking for.

You should also restructure your html.
Multiple elements with the same ID's is not good practice and can cause alot of headaches.

Comment: Why use `jQuery` over its alias `$`? Also you need to wrap `(i,e)` in a function like `each(function(i,e){...})` You're parenthesis/bracket are backwards at the second to last line too...

Comment: @Pat thanks for the spot. Reason i use jQuery instead of the alias is because sometimes the $ is reserved for other libraries. I know you can use noConflict however if the load order of your scripts are not consistent, then you may not have the "$" alias reserved for your custom jQuery